# Remove duplicates and calculate average

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code to ckeck for duplicates in Column I, removes them and sum up values in Column R, S, U and V. Now I want to Calculate avarage in Column T. Can you help me Update my code to Calculate the Average Values in Column T? Thank you!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Doppelte Entfernen"
   ' ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False                                             1
    ' Start an error-handling routine.
    
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
     
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "A4"
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 9 ' I
    Dim SumupColumns(): SumupColumns = VBA.Array(18, 19, 21, 22) ' R, S, U ,V
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    ' Check if there was a change in the unique column.
    
    Dim rg As Range:
    With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL).EntireRow.Columns(UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        Set rg = .Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
        
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(rg, Target)
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    Dim sUpper As Long: sUpper = UBound(SumupColumns)

    Dim srg As Range
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set srg = ws.Range(FIRST_CELL, .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    ' Columns("A:AE").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter        Align Center
     Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
     Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to an array.
    
    Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value

    ' Write the unique values from the unique column of the array and their rows
    ' to a dictionary while writing the unique data to the top of the array.
    ' All columns are written for each unique item but only the sumup-columns
    ' are summed up for an existing item.

    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim uVal, sr As Long
    
    ' The source data stays intact until the first duplicate is found.
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        uVal = Data(sr, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        If dict.Exists(uVal) Then Exit For
        dict(uVal) = sr
    Next sr
    
    ' Check if no duplicates.
    If sr > srCount Then
        MsgBox "Keine Duplikate vorhanden.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = sr - 1
    
    Dim wr As Long, wc As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Write after first duplicate was found.
    For sr = sr To srCount
        uVal = Data(sr, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        If dict.Exists(uVal) Then ' exists; write sum-up columns
            wr = dict(uVal)
            For c = 0 To sUpper
                wc = SumupColumns(c)
                Data(wr, wc) = Data(wr, wc) + Data(sr, wc)
            Next c
        Else ' doesn't exist; write all columns
            dr = dr + 1
            dict(uVal) = dr
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' Write the data from the top of the array back to the range
    ' and clear its excessive rows below.
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With srg.Resize(dr)
        .Value = Data
        .Resize(srCount - dr).Offset(dr).Clear
    End With
    
    Success = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error ahead
        ' Make sure to enable events!!!
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
        ' Inform.
        If Success Then
  '  MsgBox "Duplicates removed.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
' Continue error-handling routine.
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
  '  ActiveWindow.dispalyzeros = True                                            1
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't read the entire code but I know one thing: if you run through a collection and you delete some entries, you must run through the collection from end back to beginning, never from beginning to end.

Comment: If this runs for every change in the key column, it could end up averaging (eg) 3 replicates to col T, and then if you add another row for that key it will end up averaging the previous average with the one new value.  That seems like something you wouldn't want?  It would allow one outlier to throw off the average of all values entered for that key...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Doppelte Entfernen"
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "A4"
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 9 ' I
    
    Dim Success As Boolean, SummaryColumns, rg As Range
    Dim irg As Range, srg As Range, SummaryTypes, k, tmp
    Dim Data(), DataOut(), dict As Object, rw As Long, col As Long, rwOut As Long
    Dim i As Long, v, summaryCol As Long, bHadDupe As Boolean, vOld
    
    SummaryColumns = VBA.Array(18, 19, 20, 21, 22)               ' R, S, T, U ,V
    SummaryTypes = VBA.Array("Sum", "Sum", "Avg", "Sum", "Sum")  'how each column is summarized
    
    'in a worksheet code module you can use `Me` to refer to the worksheet
    With Me.Range(FIRST_CELL).EntireRow.Columns(UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        Set rg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .row + 1)
    End With
    Set irg = Intersect(rg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If Me.FilterMode Then Me.ShowAllData
    
    With Me.UsedRange
        Set srg = Me.Range(FIRST_CELL, .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    Data = srg.Value
    'create a same-size empty array for the output
    ReDim DataOut(1 To UBound(Data, 1), 1 To UBound(Data, 2))
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    rwOut = 0
    
    For rw = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)    'loop over the input data
        k = Data(rw, UNIQUE_COLUMN)  'key value
        If Not dict.Exists(k) Then
            rwOut = rwOut + 1
            dict.Add k, Array(rwOut, 1) '(row in output array, count)
            For col = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                DataOut(rwOut, col) = Data(rw, col) 'initial copy of first row for this key value
            Next col
        Else
            tmp = dict(k) 'extract array from dictionary to work with it
            For i = LBound(SummaryColumns) To UBound(SummaryColumns)
                summaryCol = SummaryColumns(i)
                v = Data(rw, summaryCol)
                Select Case SummaryTypes(i)
                    Case "Sum"
                        DataOut(tmp(0), summaryCol) = DataOut(tmp(0), summaryCol) + v
                    Case "Avg"
                        vOld = DataOut(tmp(0), summaryCol)
                        DataOut(tmp(0), summaryCol) = ((tmp(1) * vOld) + v) / (tmp(1) + 1) 'recalculate the average
                End Select
            Next i
            tmp(1) = tmp(1) + 1 'increment count of rows
            dict(k) = tmp       'replace array
            bHadDupe = True    'flag at least one duplicate
        End If
    Next rw
    
    If Not bHadDupe Then 'had at least one duplicate?
        MsgBox "Keine Duplikate vorhanden.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    srg.ClearContents
    srg.Resize(rwOut).Value = DataOut
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```